# Source code of SGI Numatools (dplace utility and kernel module)

Tags: numa, sgi

I'm curious if there a source code of SGI Numatools, which is part of proprietary package (SGI ProPack); but contain GPL code. This package consists of dlook, dplace NUMA utilities and numatools kernel module.

GPL license is listed there, in release notes of SGI ProPack: http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/linux/usr/relnotes/sgi-propack-5-sp3-for-linux-for-amd64-em64t-for-use-with-sles10-sp1/PACKAGE_LICENSES.txt

```
 numatools : GPL 
sgi-numatools-kmp-debug : GPL
sgi-numatools-kmp-default : GPL
sgi-numatools-kmp-sltdebug : GPL
sgi-numatools-kmp-smp : GPL
sgi-numatools-kmp-xen : GPL
```

Answer (score 0):

They used to claim that:

*SGI established its intellectual alliance with Open Source years before the term was coined.*

http://oss.sgi.com/

and they still provide some information about NUMA Linux support:

http://oss.sgi.com/projects/numa/

and a pointer to its SourceForge project:

http://lse.sourceforge.net/numa/

However the sources and information that you find in those links is not exactly up-to-date...